# Find the dimension of and the basis for S

Tags: linear-algebra

For

A = $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 2\\2 & 5 & 7 \\3 & 6 & 6\end{bmatrix}$,

consider the subspace of $ℝ^3$ given by

$ S=\{x∈ℝ^3|Ax=0\} $.

Find the dimension of and the basis for S.

I know the $ dim(S) = n - rank(A) = 3-2 = 1$, but I don't know how to get the basis for S.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find $\dim(S)$ linearly independent vectors $\vec{b}_i$ with the property that 
$A\vec{b}_i = \vec{0}$.

If you are right about the dimension of $S$ being 1, then you are trying to find the solution, unique up to any overall non-zero multiplicative factor, of 
$$
\pmatrix{1&2&2\\2&5&7\\3&6&6}\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\}
$$
So you need to find a non-zero solution of $$x+2y + 2z = 0 \\ 2x + 5y + 7z = 0$$
(the third equation is three times the first, so we can skip it).

You quickly get $y = -3z$ and can take $z=1$ to fined the basis vector is 
$$
\pmatrix{4\\-3\\1}
$$

Comment: So z is arbitrary and we just choose to make it 1?

Comment: Given that you have two equations in three unknowns, there will always be at least one "free" variable that you need to specify a value of to get a particular solution. The value of $z$ you choose doesn't matter so much.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure can be fully automated using the *Reduced Row Echelon Form* of the matrix: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\2&5&7\\
3&6&6 \end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&2\\0&1&3\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-4\\0&1&3\\0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
Thus the solutions are given by the formulae
$$x=4z,\:y=-3z\iff\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=z\begin{bmatrix}4\\-3\\1\end{bmatrix}. $$